# Oracle DB select between dates

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

I would like to query number of records between `night 12.01 AM to 11.59 PM` but issue is, I would like to schedule this query so I cant specify any hard coded dates.

Query should pull number of records for query date between 12.01 AM to 11.59 PM.
Could someone please help me on this.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to include any data between 00:00:00 and 00:00:59, and 23:59:01 and 23:59:59?

Comment: Why start at 12:01? If something comes in during that one-minute interval between 12:00 and 12:01, you don't want to see it?

Answer (score 1):

> Query should pull number of records for query date between 12.01 AM to 11.59 PM.

You could do it as:

- **TRUNC** gives you date element truncating the time portion
- convert the **SYSDATE** into string using **TO_CHAR**
- then concatenate the time element
- finally convert everything back to DATE

**SYSDATE** returns the current date and time set for the operating system on which the database resides. The datatype of the returned value is DATE, and the format returned depends on the value of the **NLS_DATE_FORMAT** initialization parameter.

So, you don't have to hard-code any **DATE** value if you want to execute the query everyday.

Use the following in the `filter predicate`:

```
BETWEEN 
        TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MM/DD/YYYY') ||' 00:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') 
AND     
        TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MM/DD/YYYY') ||' 23:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')
```

**Demo**

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT to_date(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  2    ||' 00:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') start_dt ,
  3    to_date(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  4    ||' 23:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') end_date
  5  FROM dual;

START_DT            END_DATE
------------------- -------------------
05/06/2015 00:01:00 05/06/2015 23:59:00

SQL>
```

So, you don't have to put any hard-coded value for current date, the SYSDATE will take care of it. All you are doing is:

- `TRUNC` gives the date element by truncating the time portion.
- Then **concatenating** the required **time element**
- Converting the entire string into DATE using **TO_DATE**

> I would like to schedule this query so I cant specify any hardcord dates

To schedule the query to execute everyday, you could use **DBMS_SCHEDULER**.

Comment: @downvoter, Would you care to explain why you downvoted?

Comment: Lalit - thank for your help. I think this query works for me. I will have this monitor for todays data and will let you know in case of any issue.

Comment: @kumarb You're welcome. Sure. You could test it with sample data. Your test case should have boundry conditions to validate that the filter predicate works properly. I tested it, and it works fine.

Comment: @kumarb Please note that you are not including the seconds portion, which means you are excluding between `00:00:00 and 00:00:59`, and `23:59:01 and 23:59:59`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you want everything that happens during the date of interest. So you want everything from and including midnight of that day and before midnight of the next day.

```
declare
    AsOf Date = date '2015-01-01 13:14:15';

select  ...
from    tablename
where   tabledate >= trunc( AsOf )
    and tabledate < trunc( AsOf ) + 1;
```

If you know the date doesn't have a time portion, just can eliminate the calls to `trunc`. But you may want to keep them just in case.